# How to use protobufs in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I'm a NodeJS beginner and I'm trying to create a protobuf object in NodeJS but I don't seem to understand the concept yet.

The .proto file I'm working with is here: https://github.com/meshtastic/Meshtastic-protobufs/blob/ab16c249dd5ed99a26ee3fe76ec84808d53d791a/mesh.proto#L889

My code looks like this:

[…]

```
const root = protobuf.loadSync('Meshtastic-protobufs/mesh.proto');
const toRadio = root.lookupType('ToRadio');
```

[…]

```
  const message = toRadio.create({
    want_config_id: 12345678
  });
  const buffer = toRadio.encode(message).finish();
  console.log(util.inspect(toRadio.decode(buffer)));
```

But apparenty, no protobuf object is created. The debug output from the console.log format shows `ToRadio {}`.

I'm looking for somewhat of a "protobufs for Dummies" explanation on how to read and use the proto files so that I can properly create objects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the quickstart and tutorial on the gRPC web site:

https://grpc.io/docs/languages/node/

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't even mention protobufs and I'm not using gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, turns out, the parameter names in Node actually differ from the parameter names in the .proto file.

e.g. "want_config_id" in the proto file changes to "wantConfigId" in Node.